# POSTing data to a server with jQuery - why use JSON?

Tags: json, jquery, urlencode

All over the net I see examples of using jQuery to make AJAX POSTs of JSON encoded data to a server. What is the point of encoding the data in JSONfirst? Why not just send it as the default data type application/x-www-url-form-encoded which would save having to parse JSON data on the server?

Comment: Do you ever wish to send anything other than a limited length name-value pair set URL encoded string? so you wish to parse the URL encoded string instead?

Comment: The URL encoded data is readily available in PHP and Java EE (JEE is what I am using at the moment), I don't have to parse it at all, PHP/JEE handles that for me afaik.

Comment: If the data you are posting isn't very complex, there is no benefit(and very little drawback) in posting with JSON. However, with JSON, you can post structures(objects) to your server in-tact and have your server-side script parse it as a structure, regardless of how complex said structure is. This would essentially allow you to have a structure that represents your data that is identical on the server and client rather than having to communicate that structure in a flat list of params.

Comment: @KevinB: Is right. JSON also allows for as much data as you can send, efficiantly. It also has a lot of acceptance.

Comment: Depending upon the platform, JSON can be handled automatically - no parsing etc - for instance .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 have decorators on methods that indicate JSON is expected and the can hancle complex data automatically.  Earlier versions also make that available with a bit more work.  One other note is that a URL has a limit on the length depending on some factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of reasons. One, it's very easy to turn a JavaScript object into JSON, while it takes effort to encode it as x-www-url-form-encoded. Also, x-www-url-form-encoded isn't really used that much any more. Besides the couple of input types that require a form, most things use AJAX nowadays. Also, JSON is much easier to debug because it's legible.

Comment: But what is the advantage of having JSON data server side? I can see the point in sending back JSON to the client browser but server side it seems to me that having data JSON encoded is just an unnecessary layer of encoding? If I send the data as x-www-url-form-encoded POST variables I can pull it straight from the "POST array" server side. If I send the data as JSON I will need to parse it before using it. If I have to do this for hundreds of clients per minute that's alot of unnecessary work, or am I missing something?

Comment: @sonicboom: The object model argumetn fits very well server side too. Form encoding gives you basic key value (that you do need to encode/decode (think %02)), but JSON gives you everything for a basic object model. Arrays, dictionaries, simple values, etc. It maps much better onto a complex backend. Anyway, someones handling that much trafic, I hope they have the power to spare to parse some JSON.

Comment: I can see that JSON can be more convenient for mapping data into arrays, objects, but performance wise it's a negative having to parse it before mapping...The Jackson JSON API has three methods of mapping JSON into Java classes and if you use the fastest method it actually takes even more code than writing the code to map Form encoded key-value pairs. Maybe there is some use case where JSON is more suitable but I can't see it for my situation.

Comment: @sonicboom: I've never used Java, so that's out of my league, but in other languages, like python or Ruby, parsing JSON is so easy it should be a crime.

Comment: @Linuxious: But encoding data to JSON just prior to sending it to the server, and then decoding it as the first task on the server is redundant imo...but like I say, maybe there is a use case where it is more suitable.

Comment: @sonicboom: But x-www-url-form-encoded is the exact same! You have to encode it before sending, and decode on receiving it.

Comment: @sonicboom - try complex data (an object with a couple dozen attributes and 2-3 arrays of a couple hundred objects each with a couple dozen attributes each) JSON handles that much easier than some name-value pairs would allow.

Comment: @sonicboom - you can create server side classes that map to the exact same (complex) structure and some platforms, for instance .Net 4.0, 4.5 and prior with some extra work, do the translation with no effort on your part on for instance a web service method marked (decorated) to return JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to use json.  If you are more comfortable using any other format, then use it.

But keep in mind, it's all strings.  And sometimes it makes sense to use a format like JSON.  What happens if you form is dynamic, and you enter multiple instances of the same thing (e.g. name1, name2, name3....)?  It's really easy to iterate over such things with JSON.  And JSON parsers are readily available for all platforms, so it's not like using it is a hinderance on any platforms.  Plus, if both submissions and responses use the same format, there is the benefit of consistency for the data in requests and responses.

Answer (score -2):

JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation, and is a way to store information in an organized, easy-to-access manner.In a nutshell, it gives us a human-readable collection of data that we can access in a really logical manner.
We use JSON encoding to organize stored information.

**Example:**

```
var jason = {

"age" : "24",

"hometown" : "Missoula, MT",

"gender" : "male"

};
```

To access the information stored in json, we can simply refer to the name of the property we need.
**Result:**

```
document.write('Json is ' json.age); // Output: Jason is 24
```

Comment: I know what JSON is, this has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: and it's JSON, not "jason".